# Saving frames and placing them into a grid using processing 2

Tags: java, processing

I want to complete two tasks here I have them working separately in two processing files but I'd like them to work in one.  I have it partly working but the two parts I need help with are:

1: I want to save 25 images in a file starting from 0 (currently start from 1)

2: I want to load these images into a grid

Any help would be great!

```
import processing.pdf.*;
import geomerative.*;
import java.util.Calendar;
PImage[] images = new PImage[25];
int ic;
PImage img;
RFont font;
int lastTime = 1;
int test = new File("/Processing2/data2").listfiles.length;
boolean savePDF = false;

void setup(){
  size(1000, 1000);

background(0);
  for ( int i = 0; i< images.length; i++ )
{
images[i] = loadImage( i + ".png" );   // make sure images "0.png" to "25.png" exist
}
}

void draw() {    
// Save images
stroke (random(75,150), random (200,256), random(50,150));
float distance = random(200);
strokeWeight(1);
line (0, distance, 200, distance);    
}    
    if( millis() >= 750){
    saveFrame("data/##.png");    
}    
//Load saved images into a grid

if (test ==25){
 ic= 0;
  float tileCountX = 5;
  float tileCountY = 5;
  float stepX = width/tileCountX;
  float stepY = height/tileCountY;
  for (float gridY = 0; gridY < height; gridY += stepY){
    for (float gridX = 0; gridX < width; gridX += stepX){
           image(images[ic], gridX, gridY, stepX, stepY);
           ic++;
    }
}
 }    
 else {     
 }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to combine two projects, but you're not removing the code you don't use. Since you are only drawing these 25 images to the screen one time, you really don't need to use the `draw()` method which continues running unless you call the `noLoop()` function. Also, you can do without the `setup()` if you're really only looking for a single execution. Otherwise, you can put most of this in setup but still skip using draw.

The following is a stripped down version of your task.

```
PImage[] images = new PImage[25];
size(1000,1000);

for(int i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
  images[i] = loadImage(i + ".png");   // make sure images "0.png" to "24.png" exist
}

int i = 0;
float tileCountX = 5;
float tileCountY = 5;
float stepX = width/tileCountX;
float stepY = height/tileCountY;
for (float gridY = 0; gridY < height; gridY += stepY) {
  for (float gridX = 0; gridX < width; gridX += stepX) {
    image(images[i++], gridX, gridY, stepX, stepY);
  }
}
```

### EDIT

According to your comment, maybe this is what you're trying to do...

```
PImage[] images = new PImage[25];
size(1000,1000);

// Save images
for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++) {
  try {
    Thread.sleep(750); //sleep 750 milliseconds before continuing
  } catch(InterruptedException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
  }
  stroke (random(75, 150), random (200, 256), random(50, 150));
  float distance = random(200);
  strokeWeight(1);
  line (0, distance, 200, distance);    
  save(i+".png");
}
// Load images
for(int i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
  images[i] = loadImage(i + ".png");   // make sure images "0.png" to "24.png" exist
}

// Display images
int i = 0;
float tileCountX = 5;
float tileCountY = 5;
float stepX = width/tileCountX;
float stepY = height/tileCountY;
for (float gridY = 0; gridY < height; gridY += stepY) {
  for (float gridX = 0; gridX < width; gridX += stepX) {
    image(images[i++], gridX, gridY, stepX, stepY);
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your response - I wanted to use the images that are saved by running the draw() function.  So essentially running the draw() once I reach 25 images, loading these images into a grid.  Hope that makes sense.

Comment: @rory I posted an edit for you to consider. I'm not sure it's what you want. It saves 25 images, loads them, and displays them in a grid.

Comment: that is exactly what the process I wanted to take, however is there any way I can get the image to save every 3/4 second rather then by frame?

Comment: @rory Is that really what you wanted? I was currently working on getting the images to show on screen one every 3/4 second rather than pause the whole time while drawing until finally showing everything at the end after a big pause.